# AngularJS, passing a service as directive attribute [undefined]

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

i'm new to AngularJS and i have troubles to pass a service as an attribute to a directive, the think is that i did this several times before, and it worked but this time i get 'undefined' as a returned value of the service.

Here's my code

directive.js

```
'use strict';

/*global d3:false */

angular.module('myApp')
  .directive('stogbars', function() {


    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      scope: {
        service: '=service'
      },
      template: '<div id="stogbars"></div>',
      link: function(scope) {

        scope.$watch(service.data,function(){
          //my treatment (scope.service ---> undefined)
        });
      }

    };
  });
```

html page :

```
<div class="rgo-data-widget box-6">
  <div class="inner-box">
    <h3 class="inner-box-title">Title Goes Here</h3>
    <div class="box-module">
      <div class="stogbars-box">                    
          <stogbars service = theService></stogbars>
      </div><!-- stogbars -->
    </div><!-- box module -->
  </div><!-- inner box -->
</div><!-- widget -->
```

i can't post the service code because it's a 700 line file. Thank's for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you injected that service in your controller ??

Your given html will work only if the respective controller has a reference of that service in the scope.

Firstly, inject the service in your controller and then Try putting

```
$scope.theService = theService;
```

in your controller.

Comment: My God, it's been 2 days that i'm stuck here for this silly error, thank's a lot mate :)

Comment: Glad it helped @Dgn (y)

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried eliminating whitespaces, in your HTML:

```
 <stogbars service="theService"></stogbars>
```

?

Comment: Yes i did, as i said, i used this method several times before in another view, but in this one it doesn't work